# getStreetViewPanorama() returning null always in android

Tags: java, android, google-street-view

While am trying to get Google Street View in my app am always getting getStreetViewPanorama() is null. Here in this url https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment they clearly telling getStreetViewPanorama() may return null depends upon Google Play services APK

**However you cannot be guaranteed when it will be ready because this depends on the availability of the Google Play services APK. If a StreetViewPanorama is not available, getStreetViewPanorama() will return null.**

But still I can't understand why it is not available with my latest Nexus 5 mobile. I hope it have latest Google Play services APK

Answer (score 0):

> I hope it have latest Google Play services APK

Better that just hoping for it:  [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29)

Comment: am sure am having Google Play Services APK. Its inbuilt app with Nexus 5. Just am not sure is it very latest version or not. But I hope it is since my mobile running with latest Android 4.4.3 version

Comment: You can check if it is the required version for your app with above method.

Answer (score 0):

From android [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment#getStreetViewPanorama()):
Returns Null if the view of the fragment is not yet ready. This can happen if the fragment lifecyle have not gone through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) yet. This can also happen if Google Play services is not available. If Google Play services becomes available afterwards and the fragment have gone through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), calling this method again will initialize and return the StreetViewPanorama.